my totolink n 151rt router not opening homepage
I have a Totolink n151rt router when I open browser configuration page 192.168.1.1 and login, after login index of / directory opens but it is not showing the GUI interface.


It is not showing the GUI interface.
From the N300RT(N100RE N200RE N150RT N151RT N301RT N302R Plus N302RE)Wireless SSID password settings you should be using 192.168.0.1 not 192.168.1.1:

STEP-1: Enter the setup interface
Open a browser, enter 192.168.0.1. Input User Name and password
(default admin/admin) on login management interface


But after reset the  router default ip address is 192.168.1.1
